# Access Denied accessing FILESTREAM on a SQL 2008 r2 from an ASP.NET Application

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, iis, filestream, access-denied

This is an asp.net app using "Forms" as the authentication mode, a single SQL user is specified in the connection string ("Server=SQLSERVER;Database=DB;User Id=user;Password=pwd;Persist Security Info=True;") and obviously access to the FILESTREAM is denied, both services IIS and SQL resides on different machines. Everything works on my development environment but the connection string here relays on the current windows user with trusted connection.

I created a SERVICE ACCOUNT and configured the application pool in IIS to run with its credentials, we added the same user to the SQL server and assigned rights to the database we need, initially I was getting "Cannot create SSPI context" as the error, then I set a connection to the server to be used from the FILESTREAM Management module which use "Trusted Connection = True" (Server=SQLSERVER;Database=DB;Persist Security Info=True;Trusted_Connection=True;), now I'm getting a denied access as well but now "Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\SERVERNAME'.", where servername is the server hosting the IIS.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: "Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\SERVERNAME'" <- that's very explicit... Did you grant that account access?

Comment: Mitch, thanks a lot for such a prompt response. Unfortunately I'm not an expert in windows, like I said, I did grant access to the SQL server to the Service Account created for this purpose, but I have no way to grant access to the machine where the IIS is running from ("DOMAIN\SERVERNAME") which in this case is apparently the problem. I tried to grant rights to the share folder to the machine and it didn't work either, I'm about to drop this project and move on. Again, thanks a lot for your prompt response and I'll really appreciate if you could lead me to a solution.

Comment: "but I have no way to grant access to the machine where the IIS is running from " - then you're stuck, unless you can get the IIS pool to impersonate an identity that has access to your server and DB.

Comment: Do you know where I could find a god sample code for impersonation? I have never deal with it. I guess that I need to elevate this issue to a higher level in the IT department, thanks a lot Mitch!

Answer (score 0):

When an ASP.NET app seeks authorization with SQL server via "Integrated Security" (Trusted Connection) it attempts to authorize via the machine name of the computer it resides in. (Technically, it attempts to authorize with the application pool's identity, for which "applicationPoolIdentity" is the built-in computer account)
These computer accounts are of the format DOMAIN\COMPUTER$

Add the log-in name DOMAIN\IISSERVERNAME$ (the $ sign is required) to authorized users in SSMS, and assign read/write privileges to the appropriate database(s).

Comment: Don't try looking up the computer name using the "find" button in SSMS; it won't check for computer accounts. Took me a while to realise that just typing the computer account in would work!